# Single backslash in string

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving this string from an external source (with a single backslash):

```
"Spool10072098_\P_18005389.txt"
```

Javascript completely ignoring "\", but I still need to get the string completely as I need to get the substring after it, `P_18005389.txt` in this case.

So my question is, how to get the substring after `\` ?

Comment: are you asking how to get everything after the / or how to remove the /

Comment: @JoeWarner Asking how to get the substring after \. Updated the question.

Comment: Remember to escape: `s = s.substr(s.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);`

Comment: So... you want to .... ***split*** a ***string*** using ***javascript***? I wonder how I'd go about ***searching*** for how to do that? What combination of words would I use...

Comment: @AlexK. Tried, but \ not seen in the argument of lastIndexOf: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/JLBgea

Comment: `.split('\')[1]`

Comment: In your codepen you need `var x='Spool10072098_\\P_18005389.txt';` to make the string *contain* `"Spool10072098_\P_18005389.txt"`

Comment: @AlexK. I'm receiving the string with a single backslash. I'm not sure if I should somehow add an additional \ to escape it, and how to do that.

Comment: If you `console.log(yourstring)` and see a single \ then everything is fine and `s.lastIndexOf("\\") ` will work.  You only use \\ when you create a string yourself.

Comment: @AlexK. that wont work it will return -1

Comment: `'Spool10072098_\\P_18005389.txt'.lastIndexOf("\\")` is 14.

Comment: We know, but he can't add a "\\" because he is getting this string from external source, so he can't modify it to add a escape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `String.raw` method:

```js
var example = String.raw`Spool10072098_\P_18005389.txt`;

console.log(example.split('\\')[1])
```

Comment: Yes, seems to be the closest to what I need. Although it's not seems to be working in Opera and IE.

Comment: That is the problem. this is ES6 so it has no full compatibility with older browsers

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you need to escape a backslash, like this:

```
/* The memory will read "Spool10072098_\P_18005389.txt": */
var x = 'Spool10072098_\\P_18005389.txt';
```

Then you can split the string using `split`.

```
const second_part = x.split('\\')[1];
```

As you told us, the string you get from some other source than your source code, has only one backslash. That's okay, then the string in the memory contains the one backslash as you wanted.

Backslash is used in *source code* to mark up various special characters. That's why, if you want it to appear in your string, you need to escape it using another backslash.

For example:

```
"\n" /* will return a string containing a newline */
"\t" /* will return a string containing a tabulator */
"\\" /* will return a string containing a single \ character */
```

Comment: Why you added another \ in string?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question how can you escape the backslash if you cant select it? its the same problem...

Comment: how so?  @SamiHult do you mean its printing / so the one in memory is // so this isnt a issue but he thought it was?

Comment: @JoeWarner I believe the problem is not real. Being unable to find the subsequence in the string is not a bug nor feature. It works as expected, if the search string contains the backslash; which in turn needs to be escaped in the *source code*. If it prints \, then there is \ in the memory. "\\” becomes \ in the memory as well, so the that's what he should search with.

Comment: but if you find yourself with a string from a service that you cant change how its returned how can you split on the / dynamically? i cant think of a solution off my head xD

Comment: By using string "\\” which, in memory, will be "\".

Comment: how can you escape it if you cant select it?

Comment: Define "select".

Comment: @SamiHult But how he add this escape on the string if when he get the string (from external source) it's already with a single backslash that really doesn't exist

Comment: No, the string, *if* it contains the backslash, will not be subject to escaping like this. It's the *search string* that needs to be escaped.

Comment: Then, of course, if the string doesn't contain backslashes at all, it becomes a harder problem.

Comment: exactly we all know that the issue is \ is not escaped but in the rare edge case scenario that i don't believe OP is in but we can just imagine that he is how would we resolve this issue its a hard one xD

Comment: I can't see how there could be any corner cases :) Either the string in the memory contains a `\` or not!